# CMake has not found a package configuration file provided by "console_bridge"

Tags: cmake, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to install Ros Indigo from source on Ubuntu 15.01

After running the following command I am getting the following error message. What should I do?

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

==> Processing catkin package: 'cpp_common'
==> Building with env: '/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cpp_common -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cpp_common'
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findconsole_bridge.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "console_bridge", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "console_bridge"
  with any of the following names:

    console_bridgeConfig.cmake
    console_bridge-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "console_bridge" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "console_bridge_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "console_bridge" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cpp_common/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'cpp_common': 
  Command '['/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cpp_common', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/cpp_common && /home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/src/roscpp_core/cpp_common -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/cpp_common -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/josephcrandall/Documents/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

    enter code here
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229294/cmake-has-not-found-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by---%22console_bridge%22/) by [jwcrandall](https://answers.ros.org/users/26303/jwcrandall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-16**:
Please edit your question and use the "preformatted text" button (101010) to make your post readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`console_bridge` seems missing. You may check: http://answers.ros.org/question/62215/where-to-install-console_bridge/

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayvenki](https://answers.ros.org/users/27992/jayvenki/) on 2016-09-16**:
Thanks Akif, As per that page you pointed i did try to install ros-groovy-console-bridge but ubuntu returns "Unable to locate package". I also tried building it as per the instructions but my "make install" did not create a share/ folder. Only Install and console_bridge and still i get the same errr

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-09-19**:
@jayvenki , seems like you have indigo release. Therefore you should install `ros-indigo-console-bridge` . Not the groovy version.

**Comment by [tough-cookie333](https://answers.ros.org/users/31795/tough-cookie333/) on 2017-09-05**:
@jayvenki Don't know why this is an accepted answer. It seems to me like you forgot to install libconsole-bridge-dev as it says in the http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi